# Is there a concept of a "free Hilbert space on a topological space"?

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, adjoint-functors

We know that if you have a map $f: A \to H $ from a set $A$ to the unit sphere of a Hilbert space $H$, you can get a bounded linear map $\tilde{f}: L^2(A) \to H$. This construction can be view as considering the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of Hilbert spaces to the category of weighted sets which is showed in the anwser https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3625350 .

I wander if one can do the same thing in the continuous situation. To be specific, if there is a continuous map $ g: X \to H $ from a topological space $X$ to the unit sphere of a Hilbert space $H$, can you still get a bounded linear map $\tilde{g}: H_{X} \to H$, where $H_{X}$ is some Hilbert space depending on topological space $X$ ?

First I try to replace the sum of elements in $L^2(A)$ in discrete situation to some kind of integral. To be specific, I try to define $H_{X}$ as $L^2(X)$ and $\tilde{g}$ as $ \tilde{g}(\varphi(x)):=\int_{X} \varphi(x)g(x)dx $. But in the problem I'm dealing with, it may be difficult to find a nature measure on the topological space $X$ . Then I want to know if I can get some idea from the view of category theory. But it seems not trivial to consider the idea of "free Hilbert spaces", even in the discrete situation you have to consider "the category of weighted sets" to avoid the unbounded situation.

So my questions are:

1. Is there some kind of " the category of weighted topological spaces" to allow you define "bounded map" from a topological space to a Hilbert space in the view of category theory.
2. If the answer of the first question is yes, does the forgetful functor from the category of Hilbert spaces to "the category of weighted topological space" have a left adjoint? If it has, what is the left adjoint?

Comment: The "weighted set" construction you cite does not work, see Martin's comment and Amaru's answer. Hilbert spaces are very poorly behaved categorically so there is just not much hope of anything like this. What do you want this construction for?

Comment: What I want is the $\tilde{g}$ in my question. And in the problem I'm dealing with, X is the zero set of some vector field on a manifold, and this vector field is not transverse in most situation I need, and I need its topological information. So X is just some topological space.

Comment: What "topological information" are you hoping to get by building a Hilbert space? Why can't you just pick an arbitrary measure?

Comment: It's hard to explain without giving the whole problem I try to solve. The difficult I encountered is the different part of X may have different dimension, I can't find a "good measure".

Comment: I don't see that you need a "free" Hilbert space in any sense (but you haven't provided details so it's hard to say, I don't know why you want a Hilbert space at all). Maybe it would be good to write down the actual properties you need whatever construction you're looking for to satisfy.

Comment: I'm kind of try to generalize  Poincare Hopf theorem to orbiford . And in this situation , you can't "count" zero point, instead of considering the number of zero point, you can consider map the zero point to the range of a specific operator, which is a Hilbert space, then this induce an isomorphism from the Hilbert space with zero points of the vector field as orthonormal basis  to the range of that operator. I'm try to generalize this ideal, so I need this "free Hilbert space"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148942/discussion-between-chen-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148943/discussion-between-chen-and-qiaochu-yuan).